# ViewPager not visible inside Activity Layout

Tags: android, layout

I'm working on an Application which contains a PageViewer inside a Layout.

But if i start it, the PageViewer isn't visible. (looks leight layout_height=0)

I never used a PageViewer inside other layouts, so maybe it isn't designed to be part of something?

Layout file (shortened,activity_tricks.xml):

```
<linearLayout>
    <TableRow>
      ....
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrapt_content">

           <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/Activity_Trick_viewPager"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="6dip" />

     </TableRow>
     <TableRow>
      .
      . 
      .
```

Trick_Fragment_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/trick_fragment_textView_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity:

```
public class TrickActivity extends FragmentActivity {     
 private ViewPager mViewPager;
 private TrickActivityPageAdapter mPageAdapter;
 public static final int FRAMES = 3;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tricks);

    mPageAdapter= new TrickActivityPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),frames);
    mViewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.Activity_Trick_viewPager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPageAdapter);
    //... do other stuff.. //
    } 
}


public class TrickActivityPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private int frames;
public TrickActivityPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int frames) {

    super(fm);
    this.frames = frames;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
    case 0: 
        return TrickFragment.init("F 1");
    case 1: 
        return TrickFragment
                .init("F 2");
    case 2:
        return TrickFragment.init("f3");
    default: 
        return TrickFragment.init("default");
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return frames;
}
}
public class TrickFragment extends Fragment {

 public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "EXTRA_MESSAGE";

 public static Fragment init(String string) {
       TrickFragment f = new TrickFragment();
       Bundle bdl = new Bundle();
       bdl.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE, string);
       f.setArguments(bdl);
       return f;

    }

 @Override

 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,

   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   String message = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
   View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trick_fragment_layout, container, false);
   TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.trick_fragment_textView_1);
   tv.setText(message);
   return v;

 }
```

Comment: Try giving the viewpager a fixed height just for debugging purposes. Some views calculate heights by measuring its children and that might be causing the viewpager not to have the correct height.

Comment: Well, that was nearly to easy ^^
Thanks for the fast answer!! Now i can see it.

But my Fragments will have different heights. Should i add the ViewPager Programmatically? Maybe this solves the problem?